# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Biology breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  1         18
Users destroyed                                 119          0
Users deleted                                     3          0
Users contacted                                   6          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           114      1,337
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               51         70
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         26        704
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              101        411
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                28      3,419
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              566      3,310
Tags merged                                       2          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          1
Tag synonyms created                              1          0
Questions reopened                               25          2
Questions protected                              68         39
Questions migrated                               49          0
Questions flagged⁴                               68        964
Questions closed                                816        654
Question flags handled⁴                         423        609
Posts unlocked                                    0         19
Posts undeleted                                  16         51
Posts locked                                      3        256
Posts deleted⁵                                  855      2,466
Posts bumped                                      0      1,900
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               13          0
Comments flagged                                  1        986
Comments deleted⁶                             1,063      1,685
Comment flags handled                           569        418
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                 103      1,486
Answer flags handled                          1,410        179
All comments on a post moved to chat             11          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Some of these actions cannot be performed by the "Community", correct? Perhaps in those cases it would be better to indicate not applicable (or similar) rather than 0.